# React Native "Failed to load [endpoint]: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run a React Native app with `react-native run-ios`, but I'm getting the following error in the debugger:

[image]

The app relies on a Django backend, which I do have running on `localhost:8000`.

In the app simulator, I see the following error:

[image]

This is related to the `Timeline` component defined in `timeline.ui.js`, which is similar to

```
export default class Timeline extends Component {
  renderItem = ({ item, index, section }) => {
    const formattedTime = formatTime(item.scheduledFor, this.props.timezone);

    const TimeView = ({ text, icon, color = 'dimgrey' }) => (
      <View style={styles.time}>
        <Image style={[styles.timeIcon, { tintColor: color }]} source={icon} />
        <Text style={[styles.timeText, { color }]}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    );

    let timeView;
    let recommended;
    switch (item.status) {
      case 'Completed':
        timeView = <TimeView text={`Completed: ${formattedTime}`} icon={doneIcon} />;
        break;
      case 'Scheduled':
        timeView = <TimeView text={`Scheduled: ${formattedTime}`} icon={doneIcon} />;
        break;
      case 'Times Requested':
        if (item.schedulingNotes.length > 0) {
          timeView = <TimeView text="Reschedule Request Received" icon={pendingIcon} />;
        } else {
          timeView = <TimeView text={`Requested: ${item.requestedTimeframe}`} icon={pendingIcon} />;
        }
        break;
      case 'Times Provided':
        timeView = <TimeView text="Times available - please select a time" icon={pendingIcon} color={COLOR_PRIMARY} />;
        break;
      default:
        if (item.recommended) {
          recommended = (
            <View style={{
              flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 5,
            }}
            >
              <Image style={{ tintColor: COLOR_PRIMARY, height: 10, width: 10 }} source={starIcon} />
              <Text style={[styles.timeText, { color: COLOR_PRIMARY }]}>Recommended</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.row} key={index}>
        <View style={styles.details}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onSessionClicked(section.key, index)}>
            <View style={styles.innerDetails}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View style={[styles.circle, { backgroundColor: COLORS[item.sessionType.categoryName] }]}>
                  <Image
                    style={{
                      height: ICON_SIZE[item.sessionType.categoryName],
                      width: ICON_SIZE[item.sessionType.categoryName],
                      tintColor: COLOR_WHITE,
                    }}
                    source={ICONS[item.sessionType.categoryName]}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1 }}>
                  {recommended}
                  <Timeline.ItemTitle item={item} />
                  {timeView}
                  <Markdown>{item.sessionType.shortDescription}</Markdown>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    let listView;
    if (this.props.error) {
      listView = (
        <View style={styles.error}>
          <Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} source={logoGreenIcon} />
          <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
            <Text style={styles.errorMessageText}>{'Apologies!\nSomething went wrong with your plan. Our team has been notified and you’ll be hearing from us soon. You can also contact us via the "Message Your Guide" button'}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>);
    } else if (this.props.loading) {
      listView = (
        <View style={styles.error}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>);
    } else {
      let text = moment().format('dddd, MMM D, YYYY');
      if (this.props.sessionsRemaining && this.props.sessionsTotal) {
        text = `${this.props.sessionsRemaining} out of ${this.props.sessionsTotal} sessions remaining`;
      }

      listView = (
        <View style={styles.subContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.textRemaining}>{text}</Text>
          {
            this.props.checkIn && (
              <CheckIn
                key={this.props.checkIn.id}
                id={this.props.checkIn.id}
                title={this.props.checkIn.titleWithDefault}
                onPress={() => this.props.onCheckInPress(this.props.checkIn.id)}
              />
            )
          }
          {
            this.props.feedbackRequested.map(session => (
              <Feedback
                key={session.id}
                sessionId={session.id}
                sessionName={session.sessionType.title}
                expertName={session.expert ? session.expert.name : ''}
                onSubmit={this.props.onFeedbackSubmit}
              />
            ))
          }
          <SectionList
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={this.props.refreshing}
                onRefresh={() => this.props.refreshTimeline(true)}
              />
            }
            stickySectionHeadersEnabled
            contentContainerStyle={styles.listContainer}
            renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            sections={this.props.timeline.map((bucket, index) => ({ data: bucket.sessions, title: bucket.title, key: index }))}
          />
        </View>);
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {listView}
        <IntercomButton />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

}
```

It seems like - presumably due to the network errors logged in the console - that `item.sessionType` is `undefined`, which leads to this `TypeError`.

Being relatively new to React Native, however, I'm struggling to see how to start debugging this problem. Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: Is the `SectionList` imported from `ReactNative` or it's your custom component? Reason is I can't seems to find `refreshControl` from the doc

Comment: [`SectionList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) is imported from React Native (as in: `import { SectionList } from 'react-native'`).

Comment: It's weird, thou I never tried using `SectionList` 
 but `refreshControl` is not one of the optional props https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html

Comment: Anyway, your guess should be right, and the problem should be coming from `this.props.refreshing` method or `this.props.refreshTimeline(true)` method, you may wanna share the methods of them. Or you wanna try debugging from this two methods

Comment: Where is the Django backend running from?